# Clone the request to a different Application in pcf

Tags: cloud-foundry, pcfdev, pivotal-web-services

I have a requirement of replicating the same traffic that was received to a production system to a pilot project(same code deployed as a diff app with minimal changes). Not sure how to do it. Can you please help me out.

App1 -> Production Application

App2 -> Pilot Project

I somehow want the same traffic received by the production system to replicate in the pilot project also. (No splitting off traffic between the apps using same route but we are talking about duplication of traffic). Is there a way to do that?

Comment: There is nothing in CloudFoundry or Gorouter that would duplicate the traffic for you. Multiple apps per route are going to split traffic and route it round-robin across apps. You might be able to use an application gateway or proxy, like https://serverfault.com/a/976156. There's probably also a way to do it at the network level, but I'm not a network admin.

Comment: Thannks for the info!!!